# How to write merge files with keys having duplicate values in cobol

Tags: file, merge, key, match, cobol

Please help to write merge 2 files with key having duplicate records.

My requirement is

```
         Key1.       Key2
          015.        015
          015.        015
          017.        017
         019.        017
         019.        019
         019.        019

        Op file needs to check
             Key1=key2
          If so,my op will be
               015
               015
              017
              017
              019
              019
              019 like this..
         I have written like this.But it is working for 015 and 
           017..not helping for 019
           Process para.
              If eof-input1 = 'N'
                 If key1 = key2
                    Move details from file2
                      to op1
                    Write op1
                    Read file2
                 Else
                    If key1<key2
                       Read file1 until eof1
                        or key1>=key2
                        If key1=key2
                         Move details
                          Write op1
                         Read file2
                        End-if
                      End-if
                    End-if
                  End-if.
```

If I have tried to write for cond key1>key2 like this  it's not working..I have no clue how to get complete op.
Please help.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Key points:

- You need to ensure **both** files are **sorted** into the same sequence. Look up the the[Cobol Sort verb](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/4.2?topic=statements-sort-statement)
- The latest version of Cobol has a **merge** statement. You may be able to use depending on

  - Program logic
  - If your compiler supports it.
- There are already plenty of Stackoverflow questions on [Cobol Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cobol%20file%20sort) and [COBOL Merge](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cobol%20merge%20file)

### General Merge logic

I find the following logic with the **EVALUATE** statement the easiest to read/debug. Assuming ascending keys, basically you read the file with the lowest key, when they are equal you have match

```
if (key-file1 > key-file2)
    read file2
else if (key-file1 < key-file2)
    read file1
else
    /* what you do here is determined by the file structure
       * one to one match -> read both files
       * one to many relationship read the `may` file */
   read both files ?
```

You stop the loop when **eof** is reached on **either** file. Then process the left-over's separately

in a more Cobol form

```
       perform  r100-read-file-1
       perform  r200-read-file-2
       
       perform until eof-file-1 or eof-file-2
          evaluate true
          when key-File-1 > key-file-2
             ...  what ever
             perform r200-read-file-2
          when key-File-1 < key-file-2
              ...  what ever
             perform r100-read-file-1
          when key-File-1 = key-file-2
             perform process-match
             perform r100-read-file-1 and/or perform r200-read-file-2
         end-evaluate
      end-perform
      
      perform until eof-file-1
         ...  what ever
         perform r100-read-file-1
      end-perform
      
      
      perform until eof-file-2
         ...  what ever
         perform r200-read-file-2
      end-perform
```

Comment: Thank you Bruce!!Already my files are sorted . I have tested like  the above method.I did not get required output ..

Comment: The code assumes ascending keys. In the question, the keys are not listed in sort sequence. Is that the sequence they occur in the file ???

Comment: My code giving succeful result for  sec1 count = sec2 count.  And sec2 count > sec1 count ..But not working for sec1 count > sec2count.

Comment: If in1>in2   (I have to check in2 key is equal to prev key and need to perform loop until it's equal to prev key)  to write op..     I don't know how to write it..Please help.

Comment: You so nor need a second loop. Make sure you are reading the correct file in at each when clause. Also try putting displays in the code to see what is going on. If you can not get what is wrong ask a second question

Comment: Hi Martin.. Morning!! I have tried adding next loop for seno1>secno2 it doesn't work ...

Comment: There is no need for more loops, you just need the main loop +the 2 loops for the case when one loop ends before the first. Have you tried putting trace displays in to see what is going on. If it is not working check the code for a logic error. I will update my answer on the logic

Comment: Yes Martin..it's going till equal condition only.. not coming to my next loop

Comment: If Eof-input2.  = 'N'
                         If key1>key2
                           Perform read file2
                           Move key1 to prev-key
                            If key2= prev-key
                              Process
                              Write op
                              Read file1

Comment: First  condition I wrote for eof-input1 = 'N'
This I wrote for Eof-input2 = 'N'